# powershell - compare username to a csv and report non-matches

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm migrating users from a legacy system into Active Directory and need to add them into an AD group. Usernames don't match (or have any logic!) between the two systems so I've got a csv with the old and new usernames in:

Input.csv:

```
SamAccountName,LegacyUsername
ChristopherSpraggons,CSprag
JakeSquirrell,JakeSq
GeorgeCornish,CornishG
```

I've written the powershell to do the lookup and add the user to the group but ideally need it to report any users that it cannot match out to a txt file so they can be done manually. I'm totally stuck on how to do this.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$ImportCSV = C:\TEST.csv
Import-module ActiveDirectory 
$InputCSV=get-content $ImportCSV
$MatchedUsers = Import-CSV 'Input.csv' | Where{$InputCSV -match $_.LegacyUsername} | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroupName" -Member $_.SamAccountName}
```

TEST.csv is just plain a list of legacy usernames with no headings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't filter the CSV data before the loop. Instead, put an conditional inside the loop and add the non-matching names to a second array:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$legacyNames = Get-Content 'C:\TEST.csv'

$NonMatchedUsers = @()
$MatchedUsers = Import-CSV 'Input.csv' | % {
    if ( $legacyNames -contains $_.LegacyUsername ) {
      Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroupName" -Member $_.sAMAccountName
      $_.sAMAccountName
    } else {
      $NonMatchedUsers += $_.sAMAccountName
    }
  }
```

I'd rename `TEST.csv` to something like `LegacyNames.txt`, though, because it isn't a CSV in the first place.

**Edit:** Since you want `TEST.csv` to be the actual input I'd suggest a slightly different approach. Load `Input.csv` into a hashtable (a dictionary) and make `TEST.csv` the input for the pipeline:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$mapping = @{}
Import-Csv 'Input.csv' | % { $mapping[$_.LegacyUsername] = $_.sAMAccountName }

$NonMatchedUsers = Get-Content 'TEST.csv' | % {
    if ( $mapping.contains($_) ) {
      Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroupName" -Member $mapping[$_]
    } else {
      $_
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ah, after using some real data it seems $NonMatchedUsers contains usernames from Input.csv that don't match TEST.csv, I wanted it the other way round.

ie - get usernames from TEST.csv, lookup against Input.csv, any that match add the sAMAccountName to the group any that dont match against Input.csv output to the $NonMatchedUsers..

is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. The update to my answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have headers in your CSV, you should be able to use PowerShell's array methods easily without manually enumerating both CSVs repeatedly.

```
$ImportCSV = C:\TEST.csv
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$InputCSV = Get-Content $ImportCSV | `
 ForEach-Object {
if ($ImportCSV -notcontains $_.UserName) {
 $_ | Out-File C:\MissingNames.txt -Append
} }
```

Comment: Thanks, arrays seem very powerful, I'm slowly learning how to use them.